# Split the array as value in Observable<any[]> to smaller chunks

Tags: angular, rxjs

I was struggling some hours to replicate a process on an array of objects with Observable but I didn't have any luck to get it done!

Imagine we have a big array like this as an Observable:

```
[ 
  {name: "you1", id: 32}, 
  {name: "you2", id: 12}, 
  {name: "you3", id: 22},
  {name: "you4", id: 54}, 
  {name: "you", id: 09},
  {name: "you", id: 43}, 
  ....
]
```

and you want to group them by 3 arrays and each arrays has 2 items like this:

```
[ 
  [{name: "you1", id: 32}, {name: "you2", id: 12}], 
  [{name: "you3", id: 22}, {name: "you4", id: 54}], 
  [{name: "you", id: 09}, {name: "you", id: 43}], 
  ....
]
```

This range is dynamic and we need to make some calculation and transform the Observable value into this form. Well, I have it done easily in Javascript but I don't know how it can be done in RXJS. Any help?

It is how it has been done in JS:

```js
        let positionArray,
            positionItem = 0;
        const totalArray = this.groupedBySize > 0 ? Math.floor(size(this.selectedWorkspaces) / this.groupedBySize) : 0;
        this.selectedGroupedWorkspaces = [];

        for (positionArray = 0; positionArray < totalArray; positionArray += 1) {
            this.selectedGroupedWorkspaces[positionArray] = this.selectedWorkspaces.slice(
                positionItem,
                positionItem + this.groupedBySize
            );
            positionItem = positionItem + this.groupedBySize;
        }
        if (positionArray < totalArray || positionArray === 0) {
            this.selectedGroupedWorkspaces[positionArray] = this.selectedWorkspaces.slice(positionItem);
        }

        this.workspaces$ = of(this.selectedGroupedWorkspaces);
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Do you need separate Observables? or?

Comment: Hey @Brandon no, I want to transform the current observable. I don't know if it is a good approach or not but I did one thing, get the value of observable, do the operation and resign it again with of(array[]) and it works. But it hasn't satisfied me. Must be a better approach

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Using rxjs partition maybe? https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/partition.html

Comment: @Brandon it is about to solve a problem in CDK Virtual scroll which needs to be shown as a grid list vertically/horizontally. The problem is that the CDK VS doesn't support the mixed orientation. so the idea was to calculate, in each row how many items will fit so we create an array of items for each row and each row will be defined as one scroll item in VS so it can work fine this way

Comment: @JonathanHamel that will separate each partition in a different `Observable` not the same one and also it is dynamic, so you can't know how many partitions you'll need

Comment: @arya then just pipe your observable and map it to the new type/structure you want. If you want the same, you should map it before you actually assign the data to the observable (probably on your http.get response). https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/

Comment: I’m pretty certain you could do this with a `scan` and a `filter` by returning null at each value if the current set is not complete and then filtering null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no more than a reduce on your array :

```js
const data = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject([ 
  {name: "you1", id: 32}, 
  {name: "you2", id: 12}, 
  {name: "you3", id: 22},
  {name: "you4", id: 54}, 
  {name: "you", id: 09},
  {name: "you", id: 43}, 
]);

const grouped = data.pipe(rxjs.operators.map(arr => arr.reduce((p, n) => {
  
  const last = p[0];
  if (last.length < 3) last.push(n);
  else p.unshift([n]);
  
  return p;
}, [[]]).reverse()));

grouped.subscribe(d => console.log(d));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

You can even create a custom rxjs operator :

```js
const data = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject([ 
  {name: "you1", id: 32}, 
  {name: "you2", id: 12}, 
  {name: "you3", id: 22},
  {name: "you4", id: 54}, 
  {name: "you", id: 09},
  {name: "you", id: 43}, 
]);

const groupArrayByGroupOf = length => rxjs.operators.map(arr => arr.reduce((p, n) => {
  
  const last = p[0];
  if (last.length < length) last.push(n);
  else p.unshift([n]);
  
  return p;
}, [[]]).reverse())

const grouped = data.pipe(groupArrayByGroupOf(3));

grouped.subscribe(d => console.log(d));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: As you can see, the `reduce` is even simpler than your JS function. As for the observable, the only thing to do is `map` the pristine stream to the one you want, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @arya I have updated my answer, see the second snippet !